# WP_Query orderby meta_key and id

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a wp_query get the last x posts order by a meta_value and ID. The prop_featured  value can be 1 or 0 . I want to get the list of post with the ones having prop_featured=1 as the first ones and then the others ordered by ID.
 Here is my arg array :

```
           $args = array(
            'post_type'         => $type,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'paged'             => 0,
            'posts_per_page'    => 10,
            'meta_key'          => 'prop_featured',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value ID',
            'order'             => 'DESC'

        );
```

I also try using filters

```
         function my_order($orderby) { 
         global $wpdb; 
         $orderby = 'wp_postmeta.meta_value, wp_posts.ID DESC';
         return $orderby;
         } 

   add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' ); 
   $recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
   remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to work with filters. My mistake is i didn't put the order after each parameter
Instead of wp_postmeta.meta_value, wp_posts.ID DESC' it should be  'wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC';

Here is the correct code :

```
      add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' ); 
      $recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);
      remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order' ); 

     function my_order($orderby) { 
       global $wpdb; 
       $orderby = 'wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC';
     return $orderby;
      }
```

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, the easiest solution is to replace your initial `orderby` by an array (and delete your `order` entry), like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => $type,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'paged'          => 0,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key'       => 'prop_featured',
    'orderby'        => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'ID' => 'DESC' )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `'orderby' => 'meta_value ID',` with `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num ID',`